# Не могу оправить сообщение в Telegram имея chad_id и token

Tags: python, telegram, бот, sendmessage

Пример взят из https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter1.html

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли, в принципе
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

В `message.chat.id` - содержит `chat_id` например `123456789`

Мне нужно отправить сообщение пользователю.

В браузере набираю:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<токен>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=Hello
```

Ответ

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}
```

Где копать?

Comment: Вы точно верно указали `chat_id`? Пользователь должен активировать бота командой `/start` и только после этого бот сможет ему писать.

Comment: Я вижу что chat не найден но брал через getUpdates

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае активация бота происходит при вводе /text

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
```

Далее пиши текст боту и должен вернуться написанный текст.

Попробуй еще так добавь msg=:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли, в принципе
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Comment: Я понимаю так. Активация бота происходит выше как вы и писали. Я получаю id_chat c (пользователем). Но мне нужно потом, через определенное время этому, конкретному пользователю отправить сообщение например из скрипта на php. Могу ли я отправить его через 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<токен>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=Hello'

Comment: Ответ полностью не верный, `content_types` принимает тип сообщения, а не команду, `msg=...` ничего не даст. Если вы хотите ловить только текст, `content_types=['text']` можно не указывать, так как это стандартное значение.

Comment: msg это ответ Telegtam (response) о результате выполнения

Comment: Что никак не решает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler()
def repeat_all_messages(message):        # Название функции не играет никакой роли, в принципе
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Вот такой код должен быть, может так заработает.